# Prove one of the cyclotomic polynomial identities

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\Phi_n(x)$ be the nth cyclotomic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.
$\Phi_n(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{\Pi_{d|n,d<n}\Phi_d(x)}$ for n>1, and $\Phi_1(x)=x-1$

Let $n=p_1^{r_1}...p_s^{r_s}$ with $p_i$ distinct numbers and $r_i>0$. Show that $\Phi_n(x)=\Phi_{p_1...p_s}(x^{p_1^{r_1-1}...p_s^{r_s-1}})$

I don't know how to do this problem, and I am not supposed to use the Mobius inversion formula. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what are the definitions that you know for $\Phi_n$ ?

Comment: I edited the question with the definition of $\Phi_n$

Comment: what I meant was that you should use $\Phi_n(x) =
\prod_\stackrel{1\le k\le n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}
\left(x-e^{2i\pi\frac{k}{n}}\right)$